# Keep sidebar fixed on top while content scrolls

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with html/css.

Hi have this design:

```
HHHHHHHHHH
CCCCCCCSSS
CCCCCCCSSS
CCCCCCCSSS
CCCCCCCSSS
FFFFFFFFFF
```

H is my header, F footer, C content and S my sidebar.

I have fixed my header at the top and my footer at the bottom so no matter how much content I have, header and footer are always showing.

Since my sidebar only has a small amount of data, I also want to make it fixed.
I want the sidebar to stay right bellow the header and always visible even if the content is too big and I need to scroll to get to the bottom of the page.

Hi have this code:

```
.container {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
.header {  
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background:#f1f1f1;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
.content {
    width: 960px;
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
.footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:60px; 
    background:#f1f1f1;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried `position: fixed`?

Comment: Hi. Yes. Already tried that but it messes with the layout. Sidebar moves all to the left and keeps above some par of the header..

Comment: try setting the right property to 0.

Comment: now its fixed on the right side but the top of the sidebar is on top of the header...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making the position of the sidebar "fixed" while stating its exact position.  So you would add the following to the div class "sidebar" in your CSS:

```
position: fixed;
left: 1110px;
top: 30px;
```

You can adjust the top and left positions to make everything fit to your likings, but this should roughly put the sidebar in the correct position. :)

Comment: Thanks. This is a "little" hack but that serves my needs :)

Answer (score 2):

Another thing you should consider is that if the user's screen resolution is less than 1110px wide, they won't see the sidebar at all. You may want to try a more fluid approach, using percentages to work out the placement - or if you want it on the right, you should really use the 'right: ' attribute instead of left.

Answer (score 1):

Fast forward to 2019, and you can now do this with `position: sticky`.

This way, the side bar scrolls as normal, until it would scroll out of view, in which case it is kept visible.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning

First experimental support was in 2013, majority support came in 2017, current support is 93%.
https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

```css
#example-element {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 20px;
}

#example-element { background-color: #ff0; border: 3px solid red; z-index: 1; }
#example-element-container { max-width: 15em; }
.box { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, .2);  border: 3px solid #00f; float: left; width: 65px; height: 65px; }
.box+.box { margin-left: 10px }
.clear { clear: both; padding-top: 1em }
```

```html
<div id="example-element-container">
  <p>In this demo you can control the <code>position</code> property for the yellow box.</p>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box" id="example-element"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <p class="clear">To see the effect of <code>sticky</code> positioning, select the <code>position: sticky</code> option and scroll this container.</p>
  <p>The element will scroll along with its container, until it is at the top of the container (or reaches the offset specified in <code>top</code>), and will then stop scrolling, so it stays visible.</p>
  <p>The rest of this text is only supplied to make sure the container overflows, so as to enable you to scroll it and see the effect.</p>
  <hr>
  <p>Far out in the uncharted backwaters of the unfashionable end of the western spiral arm of the Galaxy lies a small unregarded yellow sun. Orbiting this at a distance of roughly ninety-two million miles is an utterly insignificant little blue green planet
    whose ape-descended life forms are so amazingly primitive that they still think digital watches are a pretty neat idea.</p>
</div>
```